# Character array declaration throws null reference exception

Tags: c#

```
char[] delimiter = { ':' };
```

The above line throws null reference exception on my production server but on my local machine there is no issue. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Relevat code

```
56           char[] delimiter = { ':' };
57           string[] split = completeString.Split(delimiter);
58           int first = Int32.Parse(split[INDEX1]);
59           string second = split[INDEX2];
60           string third = split[INDEX3];
```

And the exception log says line 56 generates the exception.

Following is the stack trace

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  at *****.Method2(String str1, String completeString) in *****\Class2.cs:line 56
  at *****.Method1(String str1, String str2) in *****\Class1.cs:line 117
```

Comment: Do you have the full stack trace from the production server?

Comment: Above array initialization is valid. Your problem is elsewhere

Comment: @Sayse Yes I have tried that too but still the same exception

Comment: This code will never throw a null reference exception. Post the stacktrace and other relevant parts of code.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy but my stack trace shows me this line number as the  exception generation point

Comment: @user3275493 - It's difficult to use line numbers included in a stack trace in the way you're attempting to there. Post your stacktrace. Are you debugging this? Have you stepped through to find out what exact line it stops at?

Comment: @DeeMac there is absolutely no problem with this code on my development machine. But according to error log line number 56 is the line from which exception occurs. I have added the relevant code to the question above.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy ??

Comment: You have a working version, and a broken version. Assuming the code is exactly the same across both environments (it should be before you even attempt to solve this), the answer lies in whatever is different. What is `completeString` - where does it come from? That's the only variable there. NOTE: For this particular code example - delimiter doesn't need to be an array, you can pass in a single `char`.

Comment: Agree with @DeeMac looks like `completeString` is null. If you have different line number in stack trace and in source code, then probably you have different version of code running

Comment: @DeeMac I was thinking the same so I rebuilt the application and deployed it again.

completeString comes from the database and I searched the db for exact format and there is no issue with the db.

Comment: So you can safely say `completeString` has an identical value on both environments? It's sounding increasingly suspicious that it may not have - especially if it's coming from a DB. Is your data in sync? If you're calling the `.Split()` extension on a null object it will throw this exception. In fact, I think given the above code this might be the only possibility. I'm going to go out on a limb and say either the exception hasn't been thrown by the above code - or it is the attempt to call `.Split()` on `completeString`

Comment: I was thinking the same way so I verified the database and I'm 200% sure there is no issue with the data and the field is also not null field in the db.

Comment: Do you have any logging in place? Assuming you can't debug your live environment you could write out the value of `completeString` to a log. There's probably a lot going on between your DB and declaration of `completeString`. Could have connectivity issues, for starters.

Answer (score 0):

`string[] split = completeString.Split(delimiter);`

The above line is throwing this exception.
If it were any of the subsequent lines it would likely be an 'index out of range' exception.

I'm going to assume `completeString` is null on your production environment.

It seems there has been some difficulty in retrieving the value from the DB  if you're sure that it's not `null` in your production DB.

NOTE: As an aside, you should be coding more defensively. Include some null checks in future.

Comment: completeString is a not null field in my db and I've verified this there is no issue with the data.

Comment: Yes, but there may be some difficulty in retrieving this value, and that could be down to a multitude of reasons.

Comment: Whatever way you look at this, your two environments are out of sync somewhere. Start by getting the DB and code exactly the same.

Answer (score -2):

```
char[] delimiter=new char[]{':'};
```

Comment: Do you know the reason or are you bluffing ?

Comment: Really? If there was a problem with the declaration the code wouldn't compile.

Comment: @Neel - not necessarily, it's right, it just doesn't address the problem at all. I've had to down-vote this answer I'm afraid.

Comment: It's also correct.we can initialize at the time of declaration